# Querying Wikipedia Web API

Tags: .net, json, json.net, wikipedia-api

Here are the two example queries I'm attempting (in app I use JSON for the output data, but this helps with formatting):

Forced fail: [Gibberish](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=1&titles=ghjgjhvmjhmvjhmv&format=jsonfm)

Attempting: [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=1&titles=Stack%20Overflow&format=jsonfm)

Running this does pull back data, and I know that the area I'm looking for is in jObject["query"]["pages"]. So I noticed that in a failure, the page name/property/whatever is "-1" and querying something valid gives you unique ID for that topic.

This is the code I currently have:

```
JObject excerpt = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
if ((string) excerpt["query"]["pages"] == "-1")
    return null;
result.Excerpt = (string)excerpt["query"]["pages"]["extract"];
```

it fails on the if check and I'm fairly sure it'll end up failing on the Excerpt one as well.

1. how do I check the item in "pages" to see if it is called "-1"?
2. how do I go into the successfully queried item without knowing the page's pageid in advance?

Comment: You should iterate over all the pages returned in the query; there might be several, as in [this example query](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=1&exlimit=max&titles=Wikipedia|Stack+Overflow|ghjgjhvm|jhmvjhmv&format=jsonfm).

Comment: BTW, you probably don't need to use streams, have a look at [`WebClient.DownloadString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a JSON dictionary in JSON.NET, you can treat it as a collection of properties (`JProperty`). And you can use LINQ method `Single()` on that collection to get the only property from it. I think a better way to check whether page is actually missing is to check its `missing` property (or, alternatively, check whether it has `excerpt`). The whole code could look like this:

```
private static string GetExtract(string json)
{
    var excerpt = JObject.Parse(json);
    var pageProperty = (JProperty)excerpt["query"]["pages"].Single();

    var page = (JObject)pageProperty.Value;

    if (page["missing"] != null)
        return null;

    return (string)page["extract"];
}
```

But personally, I prefer to use XML instead of JSON in cases like this. With XML, the method would instead look like (it's longer than the JSON version, but it's also simpler, which I think is a plus):

```
private static string GetExtractXml(string xml)
{
    var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    var page = document
        .Element("api")
        .Element("query")
        .Element("pages")
        .Elements("page")
        .Single();

    if (page.Attribute("missing") != null)
        return null;

    return (string)page.Element("extract");
}
```